# Need help getting SainSmart TFT LCD working with mega

Tags: lcd, tft

I bought [ths TFT LCD](http://www.sainsmart.com/module/lcd-module/sainsmart-3-2-tft-lcd-display-touch-panel-pcb-adapter-sd-slot-for-arduino-2560.html) instead of the one I asked about yesterday. This unit has wider screen and has a touch panel.

But I can't get it working. Can't see which wires to connect to mega. I have not used a TFT LCD before.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no question.

Comment: The [link you provided](http://www.sainsmart.com/module/lcd-module/sainsmart-3-2-tft-lcd-display-touch-panel-pcb-adapter-sd-slot-for-arduino-2560.html) links to [a compressed package](http://www.sainsonic.com/zen/albums/Resource/20/20-011-918/ITDB02_Graph16.rar) containing pertinent datasheets.

Comment: @tyblu - Ah thanks, I missed it completely as it's not the usual blue link.

Answer (score 1):

Did it come with a datasheet?

If not, then you'll need to look at the PCB to see if the signals are marked. If not, then you're a bit stuck unless you have the Arduino 2650 mentioned :-( (I assume it's one of those shield things)

I would message Sainsmart and ask them for the datasheet. If they don't have one or don't give you the information promptly, I wouldn't buy from them again.
Always check whether the datasheet is available, (and is actually of some use) before purchasing - unless it's operation is obvious (e.g. transistor, LED - even then unless it's for a hobby project don't bother) it really isn't worth the time/effort.

It's based on the [SSD1829](http://www.gpegint.com/files/library/files/supportpdf/Driver%20IC%20SSD1289.pdf) IC, so it may be possible to trace the connections and check the pin functions in the IC datasheet. Not all the SSD1829 pins will be brought out to the PCB connector - they will likely be a parallel data transfer (probably 16-bit or 18-bit) with R/W, CE (chip enable), E (data strobe) and a data/command pin.

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://www.sainsmart.com/wiki/index.php/SainSmart_3.2%22_TFT_LCD_Display) you can find the datasheet
or you can purchase [a shield](http://www.sainsmart.com/arduino-compatibles/atmel-avr-board/sainsmart-tft-lcd-adjustable-shield-for-arduino-mega-2560-r3-1280-a082-plug.html) which will help you connect your tft and mega easily.

Comment: Please expand upon your answer with some background and explanation, as well as canonical source references where possible: Single-line answers are neither taken seriously by readers, nor necessarily sufficiently pedantic for long term researcher value.